# Discord bot unable to play song using ytdl-core

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am having a problem with ytdl-core. My bot can’t play anything. In my console it says `Playing: (song)` but it doesn’t play anything at all. Everything is worked perfectly except it can't play any song. Here is the code.

```
const config = require('../config/settings.json');
const queueFilename = './data/queue.txt';

const queue = fs.readFileSync(queueFilename).toString().split('\n');
const queueLength = queue.length;

async function playMusic(conn, entry = 0) {
  const song = queue[entry];

  try {
    const stream = ytdl(song, { 
      quality: 'highestaudio',
      highWaterMark: 1<<25
     });

    stream.on('info', info => {
      curSong = info.title;
      logger.info(`Playing: ${curSong}`);
      updatePresence(`► ${curSong}`);

      if (listeners <= 1) {
        dispatcher.pause();
        updatePresence(`❙ ❙ ${curSong}`);
        logger.info(`Nobody is listening in ${channel.name}, music has been paused.`);
      }
    });
  
    dispatcher = await conn.play(stream);
  
    dispatcher.on('end', () => {
      if (entry == queueLength - 1) playMusic(conn);
      else playMusic(conn, entry + 1);
    });
  
    dispatcher.on('error', err => {
      logger.error(err);
      if (entry == queueLength - 1) playMusic(conn);
      else playMusic(conn, entry + 1);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    if (entry == queueLength - 1) playMusic(conn);
    else playMusic(conn, entry + 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I don't know what caused it, but what I did was uninstall it and reinstall it, and now it works fine. 
Use these commands:

```
npm uninstall ytdl-core
npm uninstall ytdl-core-discord

npm install ytdl-core
npm install ytdl-core-discord
```